# Is there a way to show a Chromecast button inside a WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, chromecast

I am currently developing an Android application using Cordova. This working fine so far, but now that I want to add a Chromecast button to the UI, it does not seem to work. I followed the instructions provided here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/integrate

And this is what my code looks so far:

```
        var CastPlayer = function() {
            //...
            /* Cast player variables */
            /** @type {cast.framework.RemotePlayer} */
            this.remotePlayer = null;
            /** @type {cast.framework.RemotePlayerController} */
            this.remotePlayerController = null;
            //...
        };

        var castPlayer = new CastPlayer();
        window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function(isAvailable) {
            if (isAvailable) {
                castPlayer.initializeCastPlayer();
            }
        };
```

Inline script inside my index.html.

```
CastPlayer.prototype.initializeCastPlayer = function() {

var options = {};

// Set the receiver application ID to your own (created in the
// Google Cast Developer Console), or optionally
// use the chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID
options.receiverApplicationId = chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID;

// Auto join policy can be one of the following three:
// ORIGIN_SCOPED - Auto connect from same appId and page origin
// TAB_AND_ORIGIN_SCOPED - Auto connect from same appId, page origin, and tab
// PAGE_SCOPED - No auto connect
options.autoJoinPolicy = chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED;

cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().setOptions(options);

this.remotePlayer = new cast.framework.RemotePlayer();
this.remotePlayerController = new cast.framework.RemotePlayerController(this.remotePlayer);
this.remotePlayerController.addEventListener(
    cast.framework.RemotePlayerEventType.IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED,
    this.switchPlayer.bind(this)
);
};
```

Content of my index.js.

In the index.html, I added the button like this:

```
<google-cast-launcher id="castbutton"></google-cast-launcher>
```

Now when I open my Cordova app via browser (Chrome AND Chromium), the cast button shows and I can use it normally. When I open the App on Android, the Button just does not show. Does anybody know what causes this and if it can be resolved?

Comment: Chromecast is extension you can't add/install any extension.

Answer (score 0):

We could not find a solution for Cordova, but managed it in Flutter.

We had the same challenge, and we searched high and low. Finally found this solution to make it work with: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_chromecast

Make sure your flutter compiler is downgraded to 13 or below. Otherwise, you will not be able to compile. Unfortunately, their code is not supported in a newer version of the flutter compiler and the author is not going to update anytime soon.